# Defining a dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following code and want to turn a string from a file into a dictionary (to be read in and manipulated). In the following code, on execution, it comes up with an error: 'people is not defined'. Have I not defined this correctly or is the syntax wrong? This is Python 3

```
def verifylogin():
people={}
with open("moosebook.txt","r") as f:
for line in f:
    items=line.split(",")
    person={}
    person['username'] =items[0]
    person['password']=items[1]
    person['Gender']=items[2]
    person['Career']=items[3]
    people[items[0]]=person

    print(person[0])
```

Comment: Your indentation is all wrong; your error could well be caused by incorrect indentation, so please do make sure the indentation in your question accurately reflects your code.

Comment: I think you are facing an indentation problem.Where you are using people  dictionary by the way?

Comment: Also, please include the *full traceback* of your error, not just a partial exception message. Presumably there is more there than just `people is not defined`.

Comment: @user3100115: please do **not** fix the indentation here, as it is extremely likely to be the issue behind the error.

Comment: @user3100115 Don't try to fix the indentation for Compoot; it's possible the problem is related to exactly how *his* code is indented, not how you think it *should* be indented.

Comment: er - sorry so what's the answer? I just want it to read the file (which is a string of usernames, paswords, genders and careers) and print say person[0] which would output the first username

Comment: @Compoot: we don't know the answer, because what you posted now will raise syntax errors; it is not indented correctly. We suspect your *actual* indentation is also incorrect, but we cannot determine this from the information we have now.

Comment: It seems that you're reading from a CSV file, so maybe you should try using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your end intention for your script is, but the following might be helpful. Python has a built in `CSV` module that can automatically read each line of your file in as a list of columns.

Furthermore, it has a CSV [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) variation which might be more useful to you. This takes the first row in your CSV file and uses the header to automatically create a dictionary for each row as it is read in.

If your file does not contain a header row, a list of suitable `fieldnames` can be provided. By using this feature, you do not need to create your dictionary.

The following shows you how you could create a `people` dictionary. The key being the `username` for each of your rows. I remove the `username` key from `person` as it then becomes the key used by `people`:

```
import csv

def verifylogin():
    people = {}

    with open("moosebook.txt","r") as f:
        for person in csv.DictReader(f):
            print("Person: ", person)
            username = person['username']
            del person['username']
            people[username] = person

    print("People:", people)
    print("Wilma's career:", people['Wilma']['Career'])     

verifylogin()
```

So, if `moosebook.txt` contained the following entries:

```
username,password,Gender,Career
Fred,Password1,Male,Builder
Wilma,Password2,Female,Teacher
```

You would see the following output:

```
Person:  {'Career': 'Builder', 'password': 'Password1', 'username': 'Fred', 'Gender': 'Male'}
Person:  {'Career': 'Teacher', 'password': 'Password2', 'username': 'Wilma', 'Gender': 'Female'}
People: {'Wilma': {'Career': 'Teacher', 'password': 'Password2', 'Gender': 'Female'}, 'Fred': {'Career': 'Builder', 'password': 'Password1', 'Gender': 'Male'}}
Wilma's career: Teacher
```

If your file does not have a header row, the following line could be changed:

```
csv_input = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=['username', 'password', 'Gender', 'Career'])
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the comments the indention is wrong, but I guess this comes from the paste here on SO and is not the issue in your actual code.

But you two other issues in your code. `print(person[0])` will fail when executed because `0` is not a valid key for your dictionary here. The only valid keys in your code are `username`, `password`, `Gender` and `Career`. Therefore you can use `person` or `people[items[0]]`. Then you could use `splitlines` to avoid newlines in your data.

```
def verifylogin():
    people = {}
    with open("moosebook.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.read().splitlines():  # Fixed line
            items = line.split(",")
            person = {}
            person['username'] = items[0]
            person['password'] = items[1]
            person['Gender'] = items[2]
            person['Career'] = items[3]
            people[items[0]] = person
            print(people[items[0]])  # Fixed line
```